# angular material 6 sidenav use 100% page height / mat-table scroll

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-material-6

Hi I'm fighting now for hours with css - I hope you can help me:

I try to set my  to fixed 100% height.
The child mat-table should than also resize and not extend above 100% age size if it has more data rows.  (mat-table now supports scrolling and sticky header and footer rows. This is why I like to give my SPA a new design)

Here is an example how it should look:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-fullpage-scrolltable 
but this has a fixed  setting `.mat-table { height: 400px;}` (and the mat-table nicely scroll if more than 5 items are displayed) 
[image]

How can i make this height (or better the height of the whole mat-sidenav-container or body expand to 100%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
.mat-table {
  height: calc( 100vh - 250px);
  overflow: auto; 
  width: 100%;
}
```

I tried id in your stackblitz and worked

Comment: Thank you - seems working foer me also - I'm going to push it to my "real" app ( https://github.com/m67hoff/aspera-browser ) and will see what the users say.   
Thanks again - OMG: this was so easy,   Feel stupid now ;-(